# Write excel formula using Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've been searching around a lot for this but couldn't find a solution. Hope someone can help me here.
I am using Apache POI to create a simple tool. Formulas will be inputted by user, and the result will be written on file. Im stuck at extending/filling the formula.

Suppose you have a simple excel formula:

```
IF(A2=B2,True,False)
```

A drag downwards on excel would result in:

```
IF(A2=B2,True,False)
IF(A3=B3,True,False)
IF(A4=B4,True,False)
IF(A5=B5,True,False)
         . .
          .
```

Now I want to do the same in my program. I will know which row to end. i just can't get the row index to increment. I have already done it manually (writing formula in program), but now I need to use this when formula is passed by user.

I have something like this for the manual part:

```
for (int ind = 2; ind < rownumb ; ind++)
{
sheet.getRow(i).createCell(12).setCellFormula("IF(K" + ind + "=L" + ind + ",FALSE,TRUE)");
}
```

Now the user will input:

```
 =IF(K=L, False, True) OR  =IF(K0=L0, False, True)
```

I want to add this formula auto-filling (incrementing) all the way till rownumb. How can I do this?

If there is no direct way, can someone suggest some other approach, however the requirement is that the formula will be passed by user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not store it's function "in a sheet's cell" but as a VBA function. In order to be able to properly utilize excel function yourself you will need to emulate that. Check [this article about user defined functions](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html), this might get you going.